Possible differences of integer sequences and their permutations
Given a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, what are necessary and sufficient conditions on $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ so that there exists a sequence $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and a bijection $\sigma: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ with $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: a_n = b_n - b_{\sigma(n)}$? Additionally, what do $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combinations of such $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ look like?
A simple reformulation would be: Consider the operators $T_\sigma: \mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}, (b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mapsto (b_{\sigma(n)})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ acting on the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$. Let $\operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb{N}) = \{\sigma: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \mid \sigma \text{ is bijective}\}$. Describe $\bigcup_{\sigma \in \operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb{N})} \operatorname{im}(\operatorname{id} - T_{\sigma}) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$. Additionally, describe $\underset{\sigma \in \operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb{N})}{\operatorname{span}} \operatorname{im}(\operatorname{id} - T_{\sigma})$.
The motivation for this is that we want to consider the elements $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ as representing infinite sums $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} b_n$, and we want to have two different permutations of the summands to represent the same infinite sum. Therefore, we must identify $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} b_n$ and $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} b_{\sigma(n)}$, meaning that we must identify the sequences $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(b_{\sigma(n)})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. So we must form the quotient module $(\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N})/(\underset{\sigma \in \operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb{N})}{\operatorname{span}} \operatorname{im}(\operatorname{id} - T_{\sigma}))$.

I would appreciate suggestions on how to tag this question in the Tagging Room.
